# Error in running shell script while loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I wrote this shellscript file. But I get `error near unexpected token`done'`

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -lt 12 ]; do
    echo Hi
    i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Previously, there was no `;` before `do`. I read stackexchange answers and wrote `;` after `while []`, still I get error. I could not found the resolution online. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your script is run by `bash`? If you are executing it with `sh myscript`, and `sh` isn't a link to `bash`, your script is being run by some other shell (probably `dash`) which doesn't support `bash`'s ancient `$[...]` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`i=$[$i+1]` this is wrong. You probably meant `i=$((i+1))`

Comment: It's not so much wrong as antiquated and undocumented. `$[...]` was the `bash` notation for arithmetic expressions before POSIX `$((...))` was adopted.

Comment: ah, nice, I didn't know

Answer (score 0):

path to bash is incorrect, you have missed a root in path
change first line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: fixed that. But still I have problem

Answer (score 0):

Correct placement of `;` in a bash script can be tricky indeed. Here's a one-liner version of your script with semicolons in the right place:

`i=1; while (( i < 12 )); do echo "Hi"; (( i++ )); done`

Note that the `$` in variables becomes redundant for integer comparisons if placed between double parentheses `((` `))`.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly

```
$ ./ttt
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi 
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi 
Hi
$ cat ttt
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -lt 12 ]; do
    echo Hi
    i=$[$i+1]
done  
$
```